# Will I pay capital gain tax if I sell a part of my invest which I accumulated by Dollar Cost Averaging over long time?

Tags: capital-gains-tax, dollar-cost-averaging, new-zealand

I am an investor in New Zealand. Generally in NZ, there is no tax over a capital gain if the investment is done for the intent of a long-term time horizon (12 months or more). I use dollar-cost-averaging to make small investments every month. I am planning to sell a small portion of it. Suppose, I started investing 14 months ago and I invested every month afterwards. Now, I am planning to sell 1/14th of it. I wanted to know, will it be considered the first 1/14th for the tax purpose (no capital gain tax) or will it be considered the last 1/14th that I purchased about a month ago (short term investing = capital gain tax).

I apologize for the poor description. Kindly let me know if you want me to further elaborate.

Kind regards

Comment: I have heard from other NZers that the tax department hasn't really figured out the precise rules, so there's no good answer other than apply common sense. My common sense indicates that you clearly have the *intent* of investing for more than 12 months. Also I hear that NZ's tax department isn't as punitive as some countries so I wouldn't be too worried about going to jail over a misunderstanding. But I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.